# How can I make an animated timer

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, ios4

Hi I need to make an animated timer like this:
[image: image of timer]

for an iPhone Application using Objective C.

I really don't know what to do. Any Helps?

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried thus far? It seems like you want us to write a major component of your app.

Comment: I don't need you to write the code for it. I just need some advice for the animation in Objective C. And as in the app I can set the timer i need to know how to make the animation always be ok.

Comment: Animation in Obj-C is usually done using the Core Animation framework. Unfortunately, it's a fairly complex API. A good starting point is the series of tutorials by Ray Wenderlich: http://www.raywenderlich.com/tag/core-animation

Comment: Go to ray wenderlich and learn to draw a line. Paint it with origin {x,y} and destination {radius+x*cos(x), radius+y*sin(x)}. Increase the angle from 0 to 360º using a NSTimer. Slap the black area on top with transparency and a shadow made with a UIBezierPath.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [DACircularProgress](https://github.com/danielamitay/DACircularProgress), it implements a circular progress view. As others said, you would increment the progress value with a `NSTimer`.

Answer (score 1):

Just calculate the **angle** from the top using the ratio between elapsed time and the total time. Seems really simple. The timer can fire regularly and redo this calculation.

The image above looks like there are two circles with the same midpoint but slightly different radius superimposed on each other. The timer firing could also update this display.

It could also update the labels inside the circles, but I really do not understand "2 days 24 hours"....

Comment: Well "2 Days 24 Hours" have to be modified in "Hours Minutes Second" for the timer. What I need is to set a timer and make the space between the 2 circles be orange(or another color...) and while the time goes I need to make it getting shorter.

Comment: I already explained how to do that. Now you should try and show your code.

Answer (score 1):

That timer looks like it can be made using a [pie chart](http://mac-objective-c.blogspot.ro/2009/04/drawing-pie-charts.html) with a mask on top of it.
Actually, you can use a png with the black circle transparent and draw the pie chart behind.

[edit] <strike>my answer assumes you know how to handle the timer part. If you want, I could also give you some info on that</strike>
This code starts a timer that would fire a function every two seconds

```
self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(timePassed) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

You can then make a function like this

```
-(void)timePassed {
     //draw a bigger pie chart than the previous
     //you can store the previous size inside a class property or global var
}
```

Don't forget to stop the timer when you're done with it

```
[self.timer invalidate];
```

Comment: It would be great if you also give me some info on the timer part. I've started iOs Programming since short time.
Thanks.

Comment: In practice I have to make a small circle that is always the same. Then I make a bigger circle that is going to be drawn as the timer goes on?

Comment: yeah, I guess you could do it like that too. This depends a lot on how you would like the timer to look

Comment: I want the timer to look like in the image above. :)

Comment: yes, that I understood :)) what I meant if you want it exactly like that one or similar. If the print screen is from an official Apple app and you copy it, they might reject your app from store.

Answer (score 1):

This is a relative question I answered before (if u are only focusing on using the NSTimer to do animation )

[Objective c - NSTimer, CADisplayLink, Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11098311/objective-c-nstimer-cadisplaylink-thread/11098735#comment14538541_11098735)

Hope it helps you